# read json file with C# and convert it into C# object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm French so sorry if my english is uncertain sometimes...
I'm in a workplacement for a 6weeks (i'm quite new in this domain...) and they want me to to transfer the actual DB (json) to the real server in SQL and all using C#. I need to read the JSON file with the C#, convert it into C# object.

There is an example of the json DB :

```
{
  "updated": "2015-05-20T13:16:00.000Z",
  "title": "Chaîne Activité",
  "description": "Vidéos des activités diverses du Webcenter",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "77B6573B-47E4-4D60-A6FC-99E81EF05404",
      "uploaded": "2014-07-02T12:56:00.000Z",
      "uploader": "Inconnu",
      "category": "activité//Pléniére",
      "title": "Teaser de la plénière 2014",
      "description": "Marc Emmanuel de 'Tous Ensemble' et Axa Atout Coeur vous invite à la 3éme plénière.",
      "thumbnail": "/Content/img/video/activite/teaser-pleniere-2014-.png",
      "duration": 66,
      "path": "Plénière-2014-teaser.mp4"
    }`
```

and there is my class :

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UploadDate { get; set; }
        public string Uploader { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
```

Please keep in mind that i'm not a professional and thank you for your help! :)

Comment: So what have you tired?

Comment: You wanto use NewtonSoft Json nuget package to deserialize the JSON to your object. Then use whatever DB technology they use their, either EF or ADO to get it into db.

Comment: I now whave Newtonsoft and i'll see with my "boss" for ADO

Answer (score 2):

You should have your classes like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string uploaded { get; set; }
    public string uploader { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the property names match the keys in the json object. You can use [`Json.NET`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and use the `JsonProperty` attribute to map the correct keys to the correct property should you wish to have different property names to the json keys.

E.g:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("uploaded")]
    public string Uploaded { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("uploader")]
    public string Uploader { get; set; }
    //Etc...
}
```

And your json string can then be deserialized to our `RootObject` class:

```
public RootObject DeserializeJson(string jsonString)
{
    var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
    return myObj;
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your response. The problem i have with your code is VS is saying that "var" can only be used in a script and jsonString doesn't exist in this scope. If i use JsonProperty it means it replace the previous class?

Comment: `var` is an implicit type and should be used within the method where you're trying to deserialize the json string. You could also just use the explicit type `RootObject`. `jsonString` is just a string variable name I made up, you would use the variable which contains your json string. I have edited my answer to include a more clear example of what I mean.

Comment: done, no more error with "var" or "jsonString" i was just in the wrong place. Do i have to make any link to read/Convert my json files in my C# ?

Comment: It depends on how you plan on reading it. Is it from a file or from a website request?

Comment: Currently in a file.

Comment: You can use something like `var jsonString = File.ReadAllText("myJson.json");`

Comment: I found the readAllText command but i have to ask my boss because the json files are in the internal server like a NAS not the online server, but devs are working with the project on computer and when you save it's save for everyone on the team project. Anyway Thanks for your help i'll be back Monday.